# How can I terminate a process with install4j (5.1.11)

Tags: install4j

I found this [link](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/whatsnew5.html) (look for "**Support for Windows processes**"), but I can't find out how to get to this screen in the install4j UI. Any help with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found it:

Right click and select "**Add Action**" and then select "**Miscellaneous**" -> "**Check for running processes on indows**"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is also an API for it:

```
WinProcesses.Info[] infos = WinProcesses.getRunningProcesses();
int idsToBeClosed[] = ...;
WinProcesses.terminateProcesses(idsToBeClosed);
```